# Mongodb array values subtract then sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection contains 2 statuses of orders "Shipped" and "Delivered". I want to calculate the average in hours

Formula
(Delivered 1 - Shipped 1) + (Delivered 2 - Shipped 2) + (Delivered N - Shipped N)/N

here is my collection

```
    {
    trackingHistory: [
      {
        status: 'Shipped',
        time: ISODate("2022-11-22T06:30:49.000Z")
      },
      {
        status: 'Delivered',
        time: ISODate("2022-11-25T15:30:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    trackingHistory: [
      {
        status: 'Shipped',
        time: ISODate("2022-11-22T09:29:45.000Z")
      },
      {
        status: 'Delivered',
        time: ISODate("2022-11-23T19:26:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
  }
```

here is my code

```
    db.client_order_news.aggregate([
  { $match : { 
      receiverCity : 'New York',
      created_at:{$gte:ISODate("2022-11-01T00:00:00.398Z"),$lt:ISODate("2022-11-30T23:59:59.398Z")},
      "trackingHistory. status":"Shipped",
      "trackingHistory.status":"Delivered"
        } },
        { $project : { _id : 0, trackingHistory : {$filter: {
            input: '$trackingHistory',
            as: 'tracking',
            cond: {$or: [{ $eq: ['$$tracking.status', "Shipped"] }, { $eq: ['$$tracking.status',"Delivered"] }]}
        }}, } },
       {$project: { "$sum": ["$price", { "$subtract": ["$deposits.amount"] } ] }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: are all documents have one shipped item and one delivered item? Is `N` the number of documents?

Comment: yes 1 shipped item and 1 delivered item. and yes N is the number of documents.
I want to subtract shipped time from delivered time of each document and then sum all of them to get the average

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume `Delivered` has always newer timestamp than `Shipped`, one option is to use a simple `$dateDiff` with a `$group` step:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {trackingHistory: "$trackingHistory.time", _id: 0}},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      timeDiff: {
        $push: {
          $abs: {
            $dateDiff: {
              startDate: {$first: "$trackingHistory"},
              endDate: {$last: "$trackingHistory"},
              unit: "hour"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {averageHour: {$avg: "$timeDiff"}, _id: 0}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bSAXWPa1d9D)